# Connecting to SQL Server through Python in Docker

Tags: python, sql-server, docker

I've been attempting to setup a Docker container/image which can connect to a SQL Server db, based on Luis' pyodbc repo found here: https://hub.docker.com/r/lbosqmsft/mssql-python-pyodbc/

I am running Docker toolbox on a Window's PC, and have tested running the Python code locally on the PC and verified that it can establish a connection:

```
Connecting to server
DRIVER={ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server};SERVER=$SERVER_NAME;DATABASE=$DB_NAME;UID=$SERVICE_ID;PWD=$PASSWORD
Got connection
```

From within the (Ubuntu) container, I have tested the connection using sqlcmd and been able to successfully connect and run queries without issue:

```
root:/app# sqlcmd -S $SERVER_NAME,$PORT -U $SERVICE_ID -P $PASSWORD
1> select SYSTEM_USER
2> GO

----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
$SERVICE_ID
```

But for some reason, when I run the Python code from within the container, the connection will not get established and fails with a timeout error:

```
Connecting to server
DRIVER={ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server};SERVER=$SERVER_NAME;DATABASE=$DB_NAME;UID=$SERVICE_ID;PWD=$PASSWORD
WARNING:root:Database connection error. ('HYT00', u'[HYT00] [unixODBC][Microsoft][ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server]Login timeout expired (0) (SQLDriverConnect)')
```

I have verified that both connection strings are identical, and I am attempting to connecting use an SQL service ID (not Windows authentication). I have also verified that for the established Windows connection, it is indeed using the service id (by running a select SYSTEM_USER query).

Has anyone else run into similar behavior?

Comment: When you launch the container are you running it with --net=host?

Comment: I wasn't, but just tried it out now and still got the same issue.